# Using different passwords for usual login and for admin-requiring actions

Tags: macos, security, password, administrator

I use Mac OS X 10.9.3.

*Background:* I log into my profile very frequently (e.g. after closing lid) and often do it in public. Someone definetely should be able to see it, and no matter if I make it 10+ special symbols long or not. I presume this password to be known for anyone.

Also my Mavericks by default whenever I need to change system settings or so, asks the same password as I use for login. Which is known for anyone as I said before. So, I want to discontinue this vulnerability.

*Question:* What's the best way to set different passwords for significant actions and for logging in? What if I i.e. create second profile with administrative rights, then set rights of a user on my current profile and expect Mavericks to ask that newly-made admin's password every time I attempt to do something significant? Aren't there any more convenient ways to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I achieve this is what you suggested:

Make a secondary Admin account and then take away your admin privileges.

I'm almost certain that it is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: This isn't the only way, but one of the simplest. Within security the simplest is very often the best.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a yubikey from http://yubico.com to get around the initial difficulty.

It is a usb device that identifies itself as a keyboard and keys in a password when you press a button, so people cannot look over your shoulder to see you type in your password.

I don't have one, but I have a friend who does and he finds it useful. His can send two different passwords, so he uses one for system login and one for whichever password vault he uses.

If I used my computer in public more often, I'd consider getting one.